# Error importing postgres DB dump into empty database

Tags: postgresql, import, psql, postgresql-8.4

I need to import my psql dump into my fresh psql database. When I execute the following command, I get errors.

psql -U user new_database < filename.sql

Error I got:

ERROR:  out of memory
DETAIL:  Cannot enlarge string buffer containing 0 bytes by 1208975751 more bytes.

How do i fix this. Aldo, is there any method to log the import process?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most common cause is a "corrupt" SQL file. There's no easy fix. Split the file in half (`man split`), fix the SQL statements at the tail end of one resulting file and at the head end of the other, and run again. In the past, I seem to recall seeing "Invalid byte sequence for UTF-8", or something like that. I'm sure there are other causes.

[PostgreSQL has a lot of logging options](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html); set them in postgresql.conf and restart PostgreSQL. Look at

- log_destination
- logging_collector
- client_min_messages
- log_error_verbosity
- log_statement